# Intervention in pgmpy causal given evidence

Tags: python, causality, intervention-analysis, causalimpact

The `.query` method in [pgmpy](https://pgmpy.org/exact_infer/causal.html) computes the effect of one variable X on Y given evidence Z. I'm not sure Z is a set of observed covariates; if that is the case, isn't it possible that, depending on the structure of the graph, a valid adjustment set does not exist?